# tic-tac-toe AI maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to create an AI program that plays tic-tac-toe against the user using PyGame. I get two different errors depending on if I click X or O. When I click X, I see the game window pop up but I cannot actually click on any of the squares. When I click O, the game window reads "Computer is thinking..." and then crashes with the following error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\schwa\Code\cs50\pset1\tictactoe\tictactoe\tictactoe.py", line 169, in min_value
    v = min(v, max_value(result(board, action)))
  File "C:\Users\schwa\Code\cs50\pset1\tictactoe\tictactoe\tictactoe.py", line 158, in max_value
    v = max(v, min_value(result(board, action)))
  File "C:\Users\schwa\Code\cs50\pset1\tictactoe\tictactoe\tictactoe.py", line 169, in min_value
    v = min(v, max_value(result(board, action)))
  File "C:\Users\schwa\Code\cs50\pset1\tictactoe\tictactoe\tictactoe.py", line 158, in max_value
    v = max(v, min_value(result(board, action)))
  File "C:\Users\schwa\Code\cs50\pset1\tictactoe\tictactoe\tictactoe.py", line 53, in result
    new_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
  File "C:\Users\schwa\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\schwa\lib\copy.py", line 205, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "C:\Users\schwa\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\schwa\lib\copy.py", line 205, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "C:\Users\schwa\lib\copy.py", line 137, in deepcopy
    d = id(x)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I scrolled and there seems to be an endless cycle alternating between `min_value` and `max_value` being called.

Here is my code:

```
"""
Tic Tac Toe Player
"""
import copy
import math

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    x_count = 0
    o_count = 0

    for rows in board:
        for columns in rows:
            if columns == X:
                x_count += 1
            elif columns == O:
                o_count += 1
    if x_count <= o_count:
        return X
    else:
        return O


def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    possible_actions = set()
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                possible_actions.add((i, j))
    return possible_actions


def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    new_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
    if new_board[action[0]][action[1]] != EMPTY:
        return Exception
    else:
        new_board[action[0]][action[1]] == player(board)

    return new_board
    # if action in actions(board):
    #     (i, j) = action
    #     current_player = player(board)
    #     new_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
    #     new_board[i][j] = current_player
    #     return new_board
    # else:
    #     raise Exception


def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] == X:
            return X
        elif board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] == O:
            return O
    for i in range(3):
        if board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] == X:
            return X
        elif board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] == O:
            return O

    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == X:
        return X
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == O:
        return O
    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == X:
        return X
    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == O:
        return O

    return None


def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X or winner(board) == O:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                    return False
        return True


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X:
        return 1
    elif winner(board) == O:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    if terminal(board):
        return None

    if player(board) == X:
        score = -math.inf
        best = None

        for action in actions(board):
            current = min_value(result(board, action))
            if current > score:
                score = current
                best = action
        return best

    elif player(board) == O:
        score = math.inf
        best = None
        for action in actions(board):
            current = max_value(result(board, action))
            if current < score:
                score = current
                best = action
        return best


def max_value(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)

    v = -math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        v = max(v, min_value(result(board, action)))

    return v


def min_value(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)

    v = math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        v = min(v, max_value(result(board, action)))

    return v
```

Comment: @00 I made the change to raise ValueError and had the same error. As for the starting point, it's in another file called runner.py that I did not implement (I'm taking a course and the instructor implemented that code). Is it possible that the problem is my calling of copy?

Comment: I found the answer! The error was in my result function. I implemented the commented out version above and it finally worked! Edit: I did not figure out why the other version did not work

Comment: @00 my apologies. I’m new to Stack Overflow, so I don’t understand some of the lingo. I really appreciated your help